# Blackberry - How to make my Bitmap field focusable?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I tried to add Field.FOCUSABLE to my bitmap declaration

```
Bitmap _fire=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("fire.png",Field.FOCUSABLE);
```

But the method doesn't accept such arguments.
Any other possible way of making my display bitmap image in focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use style in BitmapField:

```
BitmapField _fireField = new BitmapField(_fire, Field.FOCUSABLE) {
    protected void onFocus(int direction) {
        super.onFocus(direction);
        Application.getApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.inform("Focus came to BitmapField");
            }
        });
    }
};
```